# How to filter fake website traffic, if it comes with utm-marks?

Tags: google-analytics, traffic, fraud-prevention

Example:

1. Site A (me) sells 2 000 clicks to site B. 
   Also, "utm_source=A" is used by site B owners in their Google.Analytics.
2. Then comes the fraud-man, who sends additional 10 000 visitors to site B - important - by-passing site A, with the same utm_source, and also with fake http-referer = site A. Different browser dimensions are used also.

What is different - the referral path.

I know for 100% that the only and true referall path is site-a.com/ext/ (which redirects visitor to site B, also counts g.a events and inner statistics). Fake traffic uses different fake referral paths, not the site-a.com/ext/

The problem: referall path cannot be seen if utm marks are used.
If utm is not used, the it would be very simple to filter fake traffic. But it is impossible to make our clients NOT use utm marks.

Who can filter referral path if utm marks are used? Google Analytics cannot do this

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way you can solve it is using javascript code to send a virtual pageview without the utm parameters if the referral is the wrong one, you will pass the site page as a parameter for the pageview code, but without the utm parameters.

It's something like this:

```js
var a=document.createElement('a');
a.href=document.referrer;

if (a.pathname == "FRAUDMAN (change here)")
  ga('send', 'pageview', 'MYPAGE WITHOUT THE UTM PARAMETERS');
else 
  ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Hope I've helped you.

Regards, 
Vítor Capretz

Comment: Vitor, thank you, but I'm not sure.. Does it affect client side g.a data? (site B). Because client needs an easy way to filter out fraud clicks (which came to site B bypassing my site A)

Comment: The solution I proposed was to remove the UTM campaign parameters of the fraud referrals, so you can filter it in Google Analytics.

Comment: It is impossible to remove UTM parameters because it is client's requirement. And I cannot influence on fraud referalls (the bypass my site, going strictly forward to client's site, with fake http-referer and etc), I just can possibly try to filter them.

Comment: ga(send...) - it sends data to my Google Analytics, not client's G.A on site B. That is important because client (not me) needs to see clear statistics (with his G.A)